# (Un-) formatting each form element

Tags: theming, forms

When we declare something like

```
$form['textfield'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'textfield title',
  '#maxlength' => 8,
  '#required' => true,
);
```

The output will be something like:

```
<div id="edit-textfield-wrapper" class="form-item">
  <label for="edit-textfield">textfield title: <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="60" id="edit-textfield" name="textfield" maxlength="8">
</div>
```

However, I am willing to remove the container `div` and `label` from some of my fields, something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="60" id="edit-textfield" name="textfield" maxlength="8">
```

Is it possible? Are there any examples somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) to change the theme function that is called when `theme('form_element')` is invoked; normally the invoked theme function is [theme_form_element()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6).

```
function theme_form_element($element, $value) {
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();

  $output = '<div class="form-item"';
  if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
    $output .= ' id="' . $element['#id'] . '-wrapper"';
  }
  $output .= ">\n";
  $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '<span class="form-required" title="' . $t('This field is required.') . '">*</span>' : '';

  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    $title = $element['#title'];
    if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
      $output .= ' <label for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . $t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= ' <label>' . $t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
  }

  $output .= " $value\n";

  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' <div class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</div>\n";
  }

  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;
}
```

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['form_element']) {
    $theme_registry['form_element']['function'] = "theme_mymodule_form_element";
  }
}
```

Using the code of `theme_form_element()`, you can write your own theme function, and remove the HTML tags you don't want. Take in mind that `theme('form_element')` is invoked for every form element output with the form API; if you want to change the HTML output of just a form element, then you need to check the #type value.
[theme_textfield()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_textfield/6) is the theme function that themes a text field, but it doesn't output the label, or the wrapping `<div>`, which is already output by `theme_form_element()`.

Alternatively, this can be done in a theme that overrides `theme_form_element()`.
Which approach you should use depends on if you need to alter the output in a specific theme, or for all the themes enabled in your Drupal site; in the latter case, you need to implement the hooks I reported in a module.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to remove the `<div>` wrapper, if you don't modify the theme.

Comment: Considering the theme I'm using it's a core theme, is there any way to do it without obviously hacking it?